# Why Rails 5.1 is taking too much time to run test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Before coming to Rails 5.1 we were using rails 4.2. And I am already using **spring gem** to run test cases fast. They were running in very less time before coming to Rails 5.1.

After Upgrade to **Rails 5.1** test cases are running too slow. I am using **Minitest** for automation test cases. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of help you want? It's unclear for me.

Comment: Means why they just slow down, How one can run them fast?

Comment: Try to use Zeus, its very fast. https://github.com/burke/zeus

Comment: Is running a single test slow, or is it only when you run the entire test suite? (You can run a single test via `rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:12`).

Comment: only single test case running takes much time

Comment: Check out https://hackhands.com/fast-tests-comparing-zeus-spring-rails-4-1-rspec-3/ and https://www.netguru.co/blog/9-ways-to-speed-up-your-rspec-tests